# How to fix KeyError 'statuses' while collecting tweets?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I was collecting users' tweets using TwitterAPI when i stumbled upon this error.

Since i'm planning to crawl atleast 500 tweets with different attributes and each query only returns 100 tweets maxium, i made a function.

```py
!pip install TwitterAPI
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import json

CONSUMER_KEY = #ENTER YOUR CONSUMER_KEY
CONSUMER_SECRET = #ENTER YOUR CONSUMER_SECRET
OAUTH_TOKEN = #ENTER YOUR OAUTH_TOKEN
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET =  #ENTER YOUR OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Here's how my function goes:

```py
def retrieve_tweets(api, keyword, batch_count, total_count):
    tweets = []
    batch_count = str(batch_count)
    resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': 'keyword',
                                         'count':'batch_count', 
                                         'lang':'en',
                                         'result_type':'recent',
                                        }
                      )

    # store the tweets in the list
    tweets += resp.json()['statuses']

    # find the max_id_str for the next batch
    ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets]
    max_id_str = str(min(ids))

    # loop until as many tweets as total_count is collected
    number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
    while number_of_tweets < total_count:
        print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. Last tweet created at {}".format(number_of_tweets, keyword, tweets[number_of_tweets-1]['created_at']))
        resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': 'keyword',#INSERT YOUR CODE
                                             'count':'batch_count',
                                             'lang':'en',
                                             'result_type': 'recent',
                                             'max_id': 'max_id_str'
                                            }
                          )

        tweets += resp.json()['statuses']
        ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets]
        max_id_str = str(min(ids))
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)

    print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. Last tweet created at {}".format(number_of_tweets, keyword, tweets[number_of_tweets-1]['created_at']))
    return tweets
```

After that, i ran the function as follow:

```py
first_group = retrieve_tweets(api, 'Rock', 100, 500)
```

It kept running fine until around 180th tweet, then this popped up:

```
179 tweets are collected for keyword Rock. Last tweet created at Mon Apr 29 02:04:05 +0000 2019
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cbeb6ede7a5a> in <module>
      8 # Your function call should look like this:  retrieve_tweets(api,'keyword',single_count,total_count)
      9 
---> 10 k1_tweets = retrieve_tweets(api, 'Restaurant', 100, 500) #INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
     11 
     12 

<ipython-input-7-0d0c87e7c3e9> in retrieve_tweets(api, keyword, batch_count, total_count)
     55                           )
     56 
---> 57         tweets += resp.json()['statuses']
     58         ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets]
     59         max_id_str = str(min(ids))

KeyError: 'statuses'
```

It should've been smoothly done till 500 and i've tested the keyword 'statuses' multiple times before.

Additionally, this happened randomly at different point of the tweets collecting phase, there is a time when i managed to finish my first group of 500 tweets. But then, this error would pop up during the collection of the second group
Also, when this error pops up, i can't use the key 'statuses' anymore until i shutdown my editor and run it all over again.

Here's the simple test that i always run before and after the Error occured.

```py
a = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': 'Fun', 'count':'10'})
a1 = a.json()
a1['statuses']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  use `dict.get` to get value for key `statuses`, which returns `None` if the key is not present, other gives the value for key `statuses`

```
tweets += resp.json().get('statuses')
if tweets:
    ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets]
    max_id_str = str(min(ids))
    number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
```

Comment: Hi @a-quan, I saw that you unaccepted my answer,  did something not work for you in my code?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was a bit busy yesterday and forgot to reply to your comment. The code still acted a bit silly so my plan were to run a few tests before approved the answer. So,the first time i ran your code, it worked splendidly. After a few more runs, it suddenly stopped and popped the same error again. After this happened, i shutdowned everything and tried the original piece of code which, to my surprise, actually worked. Then today, just recently, the original one failed again and your code was running fine.

Comment: So, my plan now is to probably change my approach as suggested by the below comment.

Comment: My piece of code is nothing but a check to ensure that the value from statuses key is only fetched when it is present, nothing more, your code working fine and then failing, and then my code working has to do with something else outside this, I would suggest using an IDE like Pycharm to debug your code. Anyways if my code is working fine, could you mark my answer accepted again

Comment: Additionally, the working/non-working status cycle of the code only happens after a noticable period of time between runs.

Comment: Yeah, i'll sure do, Tysm

Comment: Yes you cannot trust an external API in general to five you the correct response everytime, so you need to handle error cases, like you observed here. It holds true for any other external APIs you plan to use in the future! :)

Comment: Hi @VinayHegde I would suggest you can ask a new question for this issue, that will be more useful in solving your issue :)

Comment: What didn't work! Can you explain detail, also this actually is a great scenario for a new question as I told you before!

Comment: Ok. I will ask a new question regarding to this issue. Tysm!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response from Twitter will not always contain a `statuses`. You need to handle a response that contains an `errors` key as well. Error responses are documented here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/response-codes.html

Also, your code uses `resp.json()` to get this JSON structure. This is fine, but you also can use the iterator that comes with `TwitterAPI`. The iterator will iterate items contained in either `statuses` or `errors`. Here is the usage:

```
resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q':'pizza'})
for item in resp.get_iterator():
    if 'text' in item:
        print item['text']
    elif 'message' in item:
        print '%s (%d)' % (item['message'], item['code'])
```

One more thing you may not be aware of is `TwitterAPI` comes with a utility class that will make successive requests and keep track of `max_id` for you. Here's a short example https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py

Comment: Tysm for answering. Your comment gave me a lot of new information. This is really helpful,  I'll definitely try to apply this new information into my codes.